# DockbarX/AWN Preview is empty

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, awn, dockbarx, previews

I'm using the following components in Xubuntu 11.10:

AWN (0.4.1)
DockbarX (0.48)
awn-applet-dockbarx (0.48)

I activated the "DockbarX previews" in the "DockbarX Preferences". However the previews are always empty. This means that the space which is reserved for the preview windows is showing up on mouse over but it's empty and I can only see the underlying window or desktop.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hey :)  I've just resolved the problem here, "window previews" wasn't checked in CCSM. I did so and it's working really well :) (no need to relaunch dockbarx)

Pierre

Comment: xubuntu comes with compositing built in. why would you need to run compiz? shouldn't dockbarx work without compiz -- with the default xfwm compiziting?